# Spring bean injection in Struts2 action using ApplicationContextAware interface

Tags: java, spring, struts2

In my application, I am getting hold of spring ApplicationContext inside Struts2 action, using ApplicationContextAware interface. To invoke the Service method(Spring service), I am using the below code

```
private ABCService abcService;

abcService=(ABCService)ApplicationContextUility.getSpringBean("ABCSeviceImpl");

/**
* @return the abcService
*/
public ABCService getAbcService() {
return abcService;
}

/**
 * @param abcService the abcService to set
 */
public void setAbcService(ABCService abcService) {
this.abcService = abcService;
}
```

Here even if I cast it to ABCServiceImpl, instead of ABCService or I remove the getter/setter methods for abcService, code flow works. Can someone throw some light on this?

I found the answer. Both the cases the bean would get injected. But if we cast it to ABCServiceImpl instead of ABCService, proxy wont work. Incase you want to intercept this class using proxy.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I am trying to find out, why the code flow does not break even if I cast the instance as below. abcService=(ABCService)ApplicationContextUility.getSpringBean("ABCSeviceImpl"); abcService=(ABCServiceImpl)ApplicationContextUility.getSpringBean("ABCSeviceImpl");